# Child component is not updating by changing props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to use react-native-pulse, but having some difficulty about updating it. I use component on parent like this:

```
 <Pulse  color={this.pulseOptions.pulseColor} numPulses={this.pulseOptions.numPulses} diameter={this.pulseOptions.diameter} speed={this.pulseOptions.speed} duration={this.pulseOptions.pulseDuration} />
```

Now, pulseOptions object is changing when state changes (Have a function to do that), no problem with it and everything is ok untill here. The problem is; its transferring the new props to Pulse component, but Pulse component does not want to receive them and update.

```
  state = {


    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
    accuracy: null,

  }

  pulseOptions = {


    numPulses: 1,
    diameter:200,
    speed:5,
    pulseDuration:1000,
    pulseColor: '#8e44ad',

}
```

Pulse is receiving them like this (Pulse component):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        color: this.props.color,
        duration: this.props.duration,
        image: this.props.image,
        maxDiameter: this.props.diameter,
        numPulses: this.props.numPulses,
        pulses: [],
        pulseStyle: this.props.pulseStyle,
        speed: this.props.speed,
        started: false,
        style: this.props.style
    };


}
```

So basicly what i want is, when pulseOptions object is changed in Parent Component (its already changing when state changes) it should go as new props to pulse component and it should update itself using them. But its not doing it.

Whole pulse component is here: https://github.com/sahlhoff/react-native-pulse/blob/master/pulse.js

Thanks for your help

Edit; when state changes:

```
  changePulseProps = () => {


                                                                      //Pulse Styling
                                                                      if (this.state.accuracy <= 20) {

                                                                        angryPulse = {
                                                                          numPulses: 4,
                                                                          diameter:500,
                                                                          speed:10,
                                                                          pulseDuration:1000,
                                                                          pulseColor: '#27ae60',

                                                                        }


                                                                        return  angryPulse

                                                              }
```

And render:

```
            render () {


          this.pulseOptions = this.changePulseProps()
```

Comment: You may find some use from this article: [Anti-pattern: Unconditionally copying props to state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)

Comment: Are you actually receiving new props in your component? Because then it's just a question of implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()`

Comment: No, I am sending them, component is not receiving. It keeps initial props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the props not always updates the state of a component. The state is set in the constructor, which is called only once, if React doesn't deem necessary to rebuild the component.
I would suggest you to implement a getDerivedStateFromProps function in your child component to manage better incoming props and new state: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

Some of the logic is mixed up a bit though. The key thing here is that you need to keep the data flowing in one direction.

In the React world, this means that stateful values (values that can change over time) will automatically cause the view (what the user sees) to update when they change.

You should declare the pulse options in the state of your component:

```
this.state = {

    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
    accuracy: null,
    numPulses: 1,
    diameter:200,
    speed:5,
    pulseDuration:1000,
    pulseColor: '#8e44ad',
}
```

then call the component with values:

```
 <Pulse  color={this.state.pulseColor} numPulses={this.state.numPulses} diameter={this.state.diameter} speed={this.state.speed} duration={this.state.pulseDuration} />
```

presumably you will need to add an onChange handler to update state

`<Pulse onChange / onClick = {this.handleClick} ...rest of Component />`

Comment: Hello, I tried like your recommendation first, It gave me “maximum depth of update exceeded” error and i seperated pulseoptions object. With another component my way is working, but not with this pulse component

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of data that control a component: props and state. props are set by the parent and they are fixed throughout the lifetime of a component. For data that is going to change, we have to use state.

in the parent, you pass the props to child use props, which for the child, it think it is fixed. so it did not receive and update. it is the `React` virtual doom update mechanism.

so in the parent, change use this.state to pass it to the child.

```
state = {
    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
    accuracy: null,
    pulseOptions: {
    numPulses: 1,
    diameter:200,
    speed:5,
    pulseDuration:1000,
    pulseColor: '#8e44ad'
   }
 }


<Pulse  color={this.state.pulseOptions.pulseColor} numPulses={this.state.pulseOptions.numPulses} diameter={this.state.pulseOptions.diameter} speed={this.state.pulseOptions.speed} duration={this.state.pulseOptions.pulseDuration} />
```

Comment: First thing i tried was this method actually, it gave me infinite loop error “Maximum depth of update exceeded” error. Thats why i seperated pulse options as a different object. I tried it in text component it works, but not working on this pulse component.

Comment: @ugrdursun, you may lead call setState in a loop. please show your core code

Comment: @ugrdursun, I think in your render method, you use `this.pulseOptions = this.changePulseProps()` to get, but the method will update, so you get the error. please do not do it. it makes it in a loop. use like this way  `let pulseOptions ={...this.state.}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @borisbezzola **getDerivedStateFromProps** did the job. Just added it to child component:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){

      return {
        ...state,
        color: props.color,
        duration: props.duration,
        image: props.image,
        maxDiameter: props.diameter,
        numPulses: props.numPulses,
        //pulses: [],
        pulseStyle: props.pulseStyle,
        speed: props.speed,
        //started: true,
        style: props.style
      }



  }
```